# MinGW 64 bit simple application error

Tags: 64-bit, mingw

I have just downloaded MinGW 64 bit for Windows (I'm not quite used to Linux) on http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/?source=dlp
When I compile the following code, I get no errors:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Code 64 bit :D !" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Also, when I execute the program in Code::Blocks, eveything works perfectly (using cb_console_runner.exe). The problem occurs when I execute my program outside Code::Blocks. I get the error "The application couldn't start properly (0xc000007b)". By the way, I translated the error from french. Do you have any idea what is the problem or how I can debug this? Oh I forgot: I don't get any errors when code is empty (i.e. when int main(){return0;}).

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've seen this happen here and there when GCC's standard C++ library  (libstdc++) (or libgcc as well) is not in your `%PATH%`. Furthermore, this may also be the case that you have a mismatched version (i.e. a 32 bit version) of the same DLL in your path. Use something like Dependency Walker to determine this.

This doesn't happen when your program is empty since you are not using any symbols from the standard C++ library and thus it is not linked with your application. However when you use `std::cout` that references a symbol defined in the C++ library and thus it must be linked.

Comment: By the way, does the %PATH% is recursive? Also, is it ok to have two different versions of gcc in my path (gcc 4.7 32 bit and gcc 4.9 64 bit)?

Comment: Ok it works and I think the path isn't recursive. Also, if I have to include gcc in my path, does that mean that every computer with my application needs to have gcc installed?

Comment: See the `-static-libgcc` and `-static-libstdc++` options. Might take some work in getting them working. With Windows it should be sufficient to just copy the DLLs into the same directory as your own application/DLL

Comment: First of, I fixed the problem by using TDM MinGW 64 bit with gcc 4.8. Before fixing the problem, I was using MinGW 64 bit with gcc 4.9 (no TDM). When I was trying to fix the problem, I did use the options -static-libgcc and -static-libstdc++(this one wasn't recognized). It never worked. So I found out it was a bug.